# Dropdownlist selection should auto populate textboxes? MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use jquery for fetching data upon dropdownlist selection . The jquery method is firing and respective method call to controller which returns JSON is also doing its work i.e returning some list of customer data  But i donno how to bind to textboxs .

***Initially i worked on cascading drop down :***

**My code looks like : country/state**

**IN VIEW:**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("state",ViewBag.stateid as SelectList,"select a state",new {id="state"}) 
 @Html.Label("District")
<select id="district"  name="District"></select>
```

**AND RESPECTIVE JSON return in controller :**

```
 public JsonResult DistrictList(string id)
        {
            int identity = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            dbforentityEntities1 db = new dbforentityEntities1();
            var district = db.districts.Where(m => m.stateid == identity);
            return Json(new SelectList(district.ToList(), "districtid", "districtname"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

But now i have a different scenario like i want to display the list i am getting from Controller into view and The data should fill in the textboxe's i created

**My code till now :**

**View part**

```
   <script type="text/jscript">
        $(function ()
        {
            $('#GETEDIT').click(function ()
            {
               $.getJSON('/Home/FetchData/'+$('GETEDIT').val(),function(data)
                    {
                    $.each(data, function (i, **?????** )

//next here i need to iterate to the data and fill it in respective textboxes 
                });
$('#district').html(**????**);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**???? : in th above code means **i dont know what to keep i.e i am having more than couple of text boxes ****

Any ideas Thank you for your time

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
 for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  var elements = "<input type='text' id='txt" + listItems[i].districtid+ "'class='required' name='text_"+listItems[i].districtname+"'/><br/></br>";
   $("#yourSelect").append(elements);
   }

 $.each(data, function (i, district) {
  var elements = "<input type='text' id='txt" + district[i].districtid+ "'class='required' name='text_"+district[i].districtname+"'/><br/></br>";
  $("#yourSelect").append(elements);
});
```

**View**

```
<div id="yourSelect"></div>
```

This is static demo for bind dynamic textbox on button click for your reference: http://jsfiddle.net/n7Nr2/1/

Comment: if there are 4 list-items means will this fill the list data to respective 4 text-boxes already created ? else any suggestion friend

Comment: @supercool sorry i don't understand your comment. so you need to fill your json result to textbox right. means there are 4 list then there are four text box display with your respective data.

Comment: well you are going through for loop to retrieve data from returned json method in controller , Right . and Later i want the for loop to assign the values we getting to text-boxes which are pre-created and will be having different id's  in the view . You using **<option value ** i didn't this point . How this thing binds data to the text-boxes .Ty

Comment: @supercool hi i just update my code hope it may help you and if you have any concern let me know.

Comment: Hi mate by the look itself code looks cool but where should i add that for loop . In my above mentioned code how to fit the listelements you using ? DO i need to add in place of this how
 $.each(data, function (i, **?????** )

Comment: @supercool `listItems` is just variable as per your code it's `data `you have to use. you can use $.each or fro loop for binding what ever you want to use.

Comment: @supercool i just update my code with bot for and $.each. If you have any concern then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try append:

```
$.each(data, function (i, district) {
    $('#yourSelect').append($('<option>', { 
        value: district.value,
        text : district.text 
    }));
});
```

Comment: By this will i get the data in separate text-boxes i.e based on list items count , ' n ' no of text-boxes will create aa ? Ty so much and sorry for troubling you mate

Comment: @supercool you will need to include some more about what you are trying to achive there is not enough information.

Comment: edited once check . Any further clarity i need to provide just comment i am happy to give details .Ty for your time

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this what you need.

**Assuming pre-created textboxes**

```
<input type="text" id="tb1" />
<input type="text" id="tb2" />
```

**returned JSon format as example**

```
[{"Tb1":123,"Tb2":456,"Tb3":678}]
```

**Read the json result using $.each()**

```
   $.getJSON('/Home/FetchData/'+$('GETEDIT').val(), function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index) {
            $("#tb1").val(data[index].Tb1);
            $("#tb2").val(data[index].Tb2);
        });
    });
```

Comment: looks very detail and will let you know :) Ty